# what is the best way for angular.js to know whether passport.js session is set or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, session, passport.js

Here are the problems I have related to angular client side talking to the backend side with passport.js set up.

- If I let angular handle all my routing how would the front-end know whether the user session is still active when browsing through the site? Simplest way and best practice way?
- If we did wanted to do a verification on whether the user session is still active through passport.js would it be inefficient to do a http request every time to check whether req.isAuthenticated() is actually true?
- How can angular handle page refresh and also know that in the backend passport is still keeping track of the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions based on my own experience.

> If I let angular handle all my routing how would the front-end know whether the user session is still active when browsing through the site? Simplest way and best practice way?

Client only knows [tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication). Stateless server must be validate it in every request whose need it. So, the best way to handle session state is through the server. It only knows about state of session based on token. Please do not to confuse state validation tokens with a stateful server

> If we did wanted to do a verification on whether the user session is still active through passport.js would it be inefficient to do a http request every time to check whether req.isAuthenticated() is actually true?

It depends on how many endpoints you need to authenticate an user through its token. Public apis, such as Facebook API or Twitter API,validate token in every request.

> How can angular handle page refresh and also know that in the backend passport is still keeping track of the session?

The most flexible way to implement an authentication service is using for [example](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/), [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

I hope that helps.

Comment: if passport implemented passport-local would tokens apply in that situation?

Comment: I don't understand you. Please, could be give me an example. But, token based authentication can be used with passport local. Check this out http://passportjs.org/docs